# How to initiate a prompt for user input based on the prefix argument?

Tags: interactive, prefix-argument

The below dummy `foo` describes how I need the `prefix` variable setting to work.

I'd like the `read-number` prompt to show up only if the user entered `C-u` as prefix. In all other cases, the prefix will be read as `(interactive "p")` would usually do.

```el
(defun foo (prefix)
  ;; (interactive "p") ??
  ;; (interactive (list (read-number "Num: "))) ??
  ;; Only if `C-u' prefix is used, show the prompt for user entry
  ;; else set PREFIX to user entered numeric prefix using
  ;; the C-0/C-1 or M-0/M-1 style.
  (message "prefix = %0d" prefix))
;; Desired outcome
;;  C-0 M-x foo => prefix = 0 (no prompt)
;;  M-6 M-x foo => prefix = 6 (no prompt)
;;  C-u M-x foo => Prompt appears => User enters 7 => prefix = 7
```

Comment: **Ask Emacs**: Elisp manual, `i prefix argument` => [Prefix Command Arguments](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html). And `i interactive` => [Using Interactive](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a more elegant way of doing it:

```el
(defun foo (arg)
  (interactive
   (list (if (consp current-prefix-arg)
             (read-number "Number: ")
           (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg))))
  (message "prefix = %0d" arg))
```

`current-prefix-arg` holds the value you'd get from `(interactive "P")`.  You can convert it to what `(interactive "p")` would return with `prefix-numeric-value`.  Finally, the universal argument is represented as `(4)`, `(16)`, `(64)`, etc., depending on the times you've hit `C-u`.  It's tempting to use the `listp` predicate to detect it, but that would return `t` for no argument as `nil` and `()` are the same, so I'm using `consp` instead to explicitly test whether we've got a cons cell there.

Comment: Nice :) Learned something new!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the most elegant way but it does the job:

```el
(defun foo (prefix)
  (interactive "P")
  (cond ((null prefix)
         (setq prefix 1))
        ((listp prefix)
         (setq prefix (read-number "Num: "))))
  (message "prefix = %0d" prefix))
```

The capital "P" in the interactive form means pass the prefix arg in it's raw form. This means it is nil without a prefix, a non empty list if you call it with `C-u` (called universal-argument) or numeric if you call it with `C-1`,`M-3` and friends.

Comment: Thanks! This works. If we don't discover an inbuilt solution to handle such cases more elegantly, I will accept this as an answer. :)